# IN excel how do I get a formula to repeat but to increment row by 2

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a list of data the data is all in one column for example

```
Alabama
AL
Alaska
AK
Arizona
AZ
Arkansas
AR
California
CA
Colorado
CO
```

and I want it to move to

```
Alabama       AL
Alaska        AK
Arizona       AZ
Arkansas      AR
California    CA
Colorado      CO
```

So the formula will look like

```
=A1           =A2
=A3           =A4
...
```

Without typing the whole thing out is there a way to do this?

Comment: I would like some help with the title I feel it could be improved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in the upper left cell of the output region:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,COLUMN(A:A)+(ROW(1:1)-1)*2)
```

And copy/drag over one column and down sufficient to get 0s

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pick some cell and enter:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,COLUMNS($A:A)-1+(ROW()-1)*2,0)
```

and copy both across and down:

[image]

Comment: FWIW, OFFSET is volatile and will recalc every time Excel recalcs.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around using INDIRECT and pattern

So for the above example  I made a column with a pattern like

```
2 
4
6
8
...
```

Then I used the indirect function to get the correct value

```
=INDIRECT(CONCAT("A",C2))    =INDIRECT(CONCAT("A",C2 +1))
```

WHERE my Data is in A column and my pattern is in C column.

Then I can just repeat the 2 formulas by dragging them and I end up with what I want.

**Improvement** building on other answer

```
=INDIRECT(CONCAT("A", ROW(1:1) *2 -1))   =INDIRECT(CONCAT("A", ROW(1:1) *2))
```

So now don't need the pattern column

Comment: Indirect is a volatile function and should be avoided when Index, a non volatile function, can be used.